# How to save and load UITextField using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults, viewdidload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I save and load a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291934/how-would-i-save-and-load-a-uitextfield)

I have tried EVERYTHING and unfortunately nothing works for me. I have probably tested about 10 ways of saving and loading the UITextFields but they don't work. I have six UITextFields and want to save them when a button is pressed and load when viewDidLoad is called.

Please can I have some help as I've got to publish the app within the next day or two and I still haven't managed to do this...

Thanks,

James

Comment: If you could post some code on what you are trying it'd be very helpful

Comment: There's so many different types I've tried but I deleted the code once it hadn't worked... I literally tried everything that's listed on here and I followed several tutorials...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString* textField1Text = textField1.text;
[defaults setObject:textField1Text forKey:@"textField1Text"];

NSString* textField2Text = textField2.text;
[defaults setObject:textField2Text forKey:@"textField2Text"];

NSString* textField3Text = textField3.text;
[defaults setObject:textField3Text forKey:@"textField3Text"];

NSString* textField4Text = textField4.text;
[defaults setObject:textField4Text forKey:@"textField4Text"];

NSString* textField5Text = textField5.text;
[defaults setObject:textField5Text forKey:@"textField5Text"];

NSString* textField6Text = textField6.text;
[defaults setObject:textField6Text forKey:@"textField6Text"];

[defaults synchronize];

NSString* temp = [defaults objectForKey:@"textField1Text"];
NSString* temp = [defaults objectForKey:@"textField2Text"];
NSString* temp = [defaults objectForKey:@"textField3Text"];
NSString* temp = [defaults objectForKey:@"textField4Text"];
NSString* temp = [defaults objectForKey:@"textField5Text"];
NSString* temp = [defaults objectForKey:@"textField6Text"];

NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6);
```

**NEW EDIT**

```
  - (IBAction) saveBtnPresssed : (id) sender
  {

        NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSString* textField1Text = textField1.text;

        [defaults setObject:textField1Text forKey:@"textField1Text"];

        NSString* temp = [defaults objectForKey:@"textField1Text"];

        NSLog(@"%@",temp);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Didn't work though... Here's the code I used: http://pastie.org/2490717

Comment: oh it dint work bcz all my strings are named Temp. Rename it to temp1,temp2,etc and it should work.......

Comment: it'll work now.tested this one.

Comment: I changed the temp myself because I realised it was wrong but didn't work still :(

Comment: then it should work. its working on mine. are the textfields connected properly, right? and also nslog the textfield.text value for all the textfields..

Comment: Please email me Mayur at james@reddexuk.com, I want to ask you something in more detail...

Comment: By the way, it's all linked up :|

Comment: I did: NSLog(@"@", Assignment1.text); but it showed "@" in the log?

Comment: Added the % and it shows the text in the log now...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3206/discussion-between-james-anderson-and-mayur-joshi)

Comment: Can we continue talking on chat please?

Comment: All works now, thanks for your help! I simply put the viewDidLoad text under ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions section :)

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/) may be helpful to you.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

// saving an NSString

```
[prefs setObject:@"your textField text" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

Comment: I've just tried that and it didn't work for me. Here's my code; Code for button to save: http://pastie.org/2490681 Code for viewDidLoad: http://pastie.org/2490687

Comment: I've added an answer below about synchronising after looking at your code. Give it a try :)

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately :(

Comment: All works now, thanks for your help! I simply put the viewDidLoad text under ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions section :)

Answer (score 2):

After you set your Objects you need to call synchronise to have it saved and committed into your User Defaults like so (Using the example you provided above in a comment):

```
- (IBAction)doSaveAllNotes{

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:Assignment1.text forKey:@"Assignment1Text"];
    [prefs synchronize]; // This is to save it and is pretty important!

    NSLog(@"Saved All Notes");
}
```

Comment: Still not working, even with "[prefs synchronize];" added... :S

Comment: You need to give us more info, is the `Assignment1.text` proper text? You sure it isn't nil? Is the `doSaveAllNotes` method being called?

Comment: Assignment1.text  doesn't have any text when loaded, it has a placeholder, is this an issue? I did type into it then press save but still didn't work :(

Comment: And yes, that method is being called.

Comment: All works now, thanks for your help! I simply put the viewDidLoad text under ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions section :)